# How to get Api Body Parameter in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to get api body parameter in my view. I want to apply search filter. I am using `self.request.GET.get('query')` but it is alway giving `none`. How can i get Body Parameter Like from Postman i am sending `query:Active` in body. But i am not getting it

```
class JobsListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = JobListSerialzer
    # pagination_class = ListLimitOffsetPagination
    permission_classes = [UserIsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print('self.request.auth', self.request.auth.application.user.userprofile.user_company.id)

        qs = Jobs.objects.exclude(job_is_deleted = True).filter(
            job_company = self.request.auth.application.company
        )

        query = self.request.GET.get('query')
        print('query: ', request.data)

        if query:
            qs = qs.filter(job_status=query)

        return qs
```

Comment: What is your URL? It should be something like http://example.com/jobs?query**=**Active. In your example you say query**:**Active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual problem not seems to taking a query param(body data).
but you are not passing it properly.
You should pass `/your-url/?query=Active`(replaced : with = ).
when you pass query:Active it takes whole "query:Active" as a one key in body.

Answer (score 2):

For getting body parameters I assume you are using POST method for requesting the api. Getting the POST data is as simple as `self.request.POST.get('query')`

Answer (score 1):

In pure Django, the way to get the contents of the *body* would be to use `request.POST`, and to get the query params would be to use the `request.GET`. Since it seems that you are using Django rest framework view, it is recommended to instead use its `request.data` and `request.query_params`.

Assuming that postman sends the data properly formatted, in this case you could then use:

```
query = self.request.data.get("query")
```